# SyntaxError: invalid syntax - Python Beginner

Tags: python, if-statement

I have decided to learn something new during my free time.  i am giving Python another go after quitting.  I am trying to create a program that covert user body weight in pounds and kilos.  I have managed to create successfully if I decide whether is Kg or pounds.  however the user to have the ability to chose whether they inputting in KG or Pounds.  the first part it works ok. If i choose KG no problem.  I get a problem with the elif code is entered.   Please see code below, thanks in advance.

---

```
choice = input("Do you Want to Calculate in Pounds or KG? ")
if choice == "KG":
  weight_KG = input("What is your Weight in KG? ")
  weight_pounds = float(weight_KG) * 2.204
  print("Your Weight in Pounds is " + str(weight_pounds))
elif choice == "Pounds":
  Pounds_Weight = input("What is your Weight in Pounds? ")
  kg_Weight = float(Pounds_Weight) * 0.45
  print(kg_Weight)
else :
  print("Invalid Value")
```

Comment: Welcome to Python (again!). Could you indent your code properly -- or at least the way it's indented in your editor?

Comment: Hey there, welcome to stackoverflow. Could you please format your code better? It's easier for people to read and help you and, in the case of python, which depends heavily on indentetion, it's critical. For example, place triple backticks \``` at the start and end of code block to format it.

Comment: What's the exact error with trace? I can't see anything obvious here.

Comment: This code works fine for me. No errors.

Comment: Works for me as well.

Comment: I don't understand the issue, please check your spelling and interpunction, I've checked the code, it converts for both kg and pounds without any issues. I suggest using ```raise``` statement for invalid value.
Also check your indentations since there may be some rogue space in front your line. One more thing I could suggest is to round your ```output```

Comment: Hi Eveyone, thanks for all your help.  It looks like it was the formatting of the code.  I have re adjusted and it is working.  Thank you everyone

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code is working fine. I have found only intended error.
choice = input("Do you Want to Calculate in Pounds or KG? ")

```
choice = input("Do you Want to Calculate in Pounds or KG? ")

    if choice == "KG":
        
    
        weight_KG = input("What is your Weight in KG? ")
    
        weight_pounds = float(weight_KG) * 2.204
    
        print("Your Weight in Pounds is " + str(weight_pounds))
    
    elif choice == "Pounds":
    
        Pounds_Weight = input("What is your Weight in Pounds? ")
    
        kg_Weight = float(Pounds_Weight) * 0.45
    
        print(kg_Weight)
    
    else :
    
        print("Invalid Value")
```

Comment: not clear what is that answer?

Comment: As I checked your code is working fine. I just got intended error.

Comment: did you mean identation error? (syntax error)?

Comment: yes, That is what I found